# How to use java StringUtils function substringBetween in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, scale, user-defined-functions

In java we can get sub-string of given String using below code

`String filename = "abc.def.ghi";`

```
StringUtils.substringAfter(filename, ".");


then output is : def.ghi
```

same sub-string functionality ,how can we achieve in scala ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it similarly in Scala:

```
scala> filename.substring(filename.indexOf('.') + 1, filename.length)
res17: String = def.ghi
```

You can also use higher-order functions:

```
scala> filename.drop(filename.indexOf('.') + 1)
res18: String = def.ghi
```

Comment: Higherly ordered: `(filename dropWhile (_ != '.')) drop 1`